In AWS API gateway, how can we disable caching for a specific endpoint
We have an API gateway (REST) and we want to disable the caching for a specific get request, is that possible?
Disable caching for the entire stage is not what we're looking for.
Moving this endpoint to another API endpoint is not prefered.

according to this and this you should be able to that by overriding the stage endpoint and disabling the caching for that particular endpoint this is now an edit
